# Nonparametric/nonlinear regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I am looking for a survey/book on some state-of-the-art non-parametric (or nonlinear regression) methods, preferably with an inclination towards sequential data. Untill now I have used `gaussian process` regression and some others such as `knn` regression, `Random Forest` regression, etc. I am looking for other possible regressors for example `particle filtering` based regression, etc. As mentioned earlier, a recent survey would be great.

Comment: 1) Nonparametric and nonlinear regression can overlap but definitely don’t have to, so what are you looking to do? 2) Neural nets :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this textbook is a good place to start: [https://www.amazon.com/High-Dimensional-Statistics-Non-Asymptotic-Statistical-Probabilistic-ebook/dp/B07N46XF8B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N46XF8B)

This is a fairly sophisticated text, I consider it a research-level introduction to many nonparametric methods and you can think of this as a more mathematically intense [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/).

I'd also encourage you to take a look at sieve estimators which are quite a popular method in the econometrics literature but I think unfortunately overlooked in some other fields. These estimators are very useful as they nest many types of nonparametric estimation procedures from series estimators to neural networks and even plain old linear regression. There is actually a nice and easy youtube video explaining them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqecz-DL-jI

For a more sophisticated approach including inference, results see: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157344120706076X

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following link gives a comprehensive summary of the different methods.

http://stat.columbia.edu/~porbanz/npb-tutorial.html

posting this as an answer so that this may come of use to someone else